# How to get the comment and count children in spring data

Tags: jpa, java-8, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to get, in a single request query, a comment and its count of children depending on an article and a comment parent.

Here is my Comment entity:

```
@Entity
@Builder
@Data
public class Comment extends AbstractEntity {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue
 private Long id;

 private String firstname;
 private String lastname;
 private String email;
 private String title;
 private Integer depth;

 @Lob
 private String message;

 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @JsonIgnore
 private Article article;

 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @JsonIgnore
 private Comment parent;
}
```

How I would do in SQL:

```
String query = "select c.*, (SELECT COUNT(p.id) from comment p where p.id = c.parent_id) from comment c where c.article_id = ?1 and (c.parent_id is null or c.parent_id =?2) ";
```

I tried several option using @Query in my Repository, I also tried with QueryDSL but I don't have enough experience with both of it. For now, I'm doing two queries per rows, one to get the comment, the other one to get the count of children.

Here is my repository:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface CommentRepository extends JpaRepository<Comment, Long> {

  List<Comment> findByArticle(Article article);

  List<Comment> findByArticleAndParent(Article article, Comment comment);

  Long countByParent(Comment comment);

}
```

Here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/article/{slug}/{id}/comment", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String comments(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id, @PathVariable(value = "slug") String slug,
                       @RequestParam(required = false, value = "parent_id") Long parentId
        , ModelMap modelMap) {
    CommentService commentService = this.blogService.getCommentService();
    Comment parent = Objects.isNull(parentId) ? null : commentService.findOneById(parentId);
    List<Comment> comments = blogService.comments(id, slug, parent);
    Map<Comment, Long> commentsAndCountChildren = comments.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), commentService::countByParent));
    modelMap.addAttribute("comments", commentsAndCountChildren)

    ;
    return "blog/comments";
}
```

I'm trying to develop a lazy comment-system (like facebook) where we show 5 more comments each time the customer click on the button. A comment can have a children, and to see the 5 next sub-comments of this comment, the user needs to click again in another button etc.

Thank you.